# different SHA256SUM Checksum value

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I trying to download and prepare bootable SD card for Raspberry PI3. The Linux Ubuntu Mate was chosen for it. After downloading and unzipping I have different SHA256SUM Checksum  value. http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/ says that I must have:

```
 dc3afcad68a5de3ba683dc30d2093a3b5b3cd6b2c16c0b5de8d50fede78f75c2

 # sha256sum ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img
```

gives

```
 aa262afd96c3e6fb26a3854347499d1c5da3fadb7240a9ad4203a55e400e5770
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should re-download the disk image. Make sure you're downloading the image for Raspberry Pi (I know you knew that, but I had to say it).

http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

I just downloaded it from the Ubuntu Mate website and I got

```
dc3afcad68a5de3ba683dc30d2093a3b5b3cd6b2c16c0b5de8d50fede78f75c2
```

Just as it had stated on the website.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to re-download anything. Your checksum is correct, but it belongs to un-XZ archive (ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img file). Checksum from Ubuntu Mate download site is also correct but for XZ-ed file (ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz).